# How to move from Scene to another Scene in As3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have two scene in my flash file , and I want to move from scene to the next scene and add fade effect when moving

can any one help please?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to make crossfade if you don't have the bitmap of first frame of your next scene stored somewhere.

To make a simple fade-out/fade-in just add a layer with a box movie clip of fitting color on top of your content in each of your scenes.

The box should be transparent when you want fade to happen.
Fade the box in. Call nextScene() when the box is fully visible.
Fade out the next box. Voila! You have your next scene through a rather smooth transition.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Nek for your answer, I will try this way to fade between my scene , but I want to actually know the AS3 code that move from scene to another , because when i served the internet for it i found some ways but it doesn't work with me , like add label to my scene and then call gotoandplay("myLabel");, waiting for your reply, Thank you very much

Comment: Actually I was thinking you had problem with fade. There are two commands to move between scenes nextScene() and prevScene().